# Particionado Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Tengo una situacion con ubuntu, tengo un disco de 250 Gb que esta en raid 1 +0 LVM con la utilidad de arreglo del servidor y otro disco de 600 Gb (que usare para montar y generar respaldos).
El tema es que al instalar ubuntu (sistema estandar), solo creo una particion / raiz y la swap (de hecho la creo con el particionado guiado). Pero al momento de consultar (fdisk -l) veo lo siguiente:

```
root@sop138:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 558.9 GiB, 600093712384 bytes, 1172058032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2ee04e7a


Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240021504000 bytes, 468792000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdaf3ad36

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 466790399 466788352 222.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       466792446 468791295   1998850   976M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       466792448 468791295   1998848   976M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Me arroja ese mensaje de error que segun he leido es porque esta mal calculado. Sin embargo para solucionarlo no entiendo como, ni cual vendria siendo la particion 2. Alguien me podria orientar?

Comment: `Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes` Tal vez su disco duro tenga Advanced Format 4096-byte sectors en la que el partición no esta perfectamente alineada. Tal vez puedes [leer esto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156994/partition-does-not-start-on-physical-sector-boundary) pero es en inglès

Comment: no puedo utilizar gparted, solo cli. Por otra parte el disco duro solo tiene la particion swap, y todo el resto esta instalado en la otra particion. Por consiguiente si modifico dicha particion no dañaria el sistema de arranque del sistema?

Comment: Al contrario, pienso que hay riesgos como lo dice el articulo

Comment: y entonces como puedo particionar correctamente el sistema al momento de instalar? se supone que el particionado guiado no deberia entrar en esos "detalles". =/

Comment: Si lo instalas de nuevo elige particionar GPT así no tendrás particion extendida. Si lo particionas en modo MBR te va a crear una partición extendida, que es como si tuvieras otro disco, y después de esta, todas las particiones son particiones lógicas. Yo quitaría la paticion swap del /etc/fstab para que no la monte, y luego borras la partición 2 y 5. Comprueba que arranca bien y desde dentro usa gparted para que lo arregle.